In proof of Theorem 10.28 in the John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian manifolds ( Second question )
I am reading the John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian manifold book, proof of Theorem 10.28 and stuck at understanding some argument.

Theorem 10.28. Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. Suppose $\gamma : [a,b] \to M$ is a unit-speed geodesic segment without interior conjugate points. If $V$ is any proper normal piecewise smooth vector field along $\gamma$, then $I(V,V) \ge 0$ ( index form of $\gamma$ ) with equality if and only if $V$ is a Jacobi field. In particular, if $\gamma(b)$ is not conjugate to $\gamma(a)$ along $\gamma$, then $I(V,V) >0$.

Proof. To simplifythe notation, we can assume (after replacing $t$ by $t-a$) that $a=0$. Let $p=\gamma(0)$, and let $(w_1, \dots , w_n)$ be an orthonormal basis for $T_pM$. chosen so that $w_1=\gamma'(0)$. For each $\alpha=2, \dots,n$, let $J_{\alpha}$ be the unique normal Jacobi field along $\gamma$ satisfying $J_{\alpha}(0)=0$ and $D_t J_{\alpha}(0)=w_{\alpha}$.
Our assumption that $\gamma$ has no interior conjugate points guarantees that no linear combination of the $J_{\alpha}(t)$'s can vanish for any $t\in (0,b)$ ( $\because$ In proof of Theorem 10.28 in the John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian manifolds ( First question, Question about interior conjugate points ) ), and thus $(J_{\alpha}(t))$ forms a basis for the orthogonal complement of $\gamma'(t)$ in $T_{\gamma(t)}M$ for each such $t$.
Thus, given $V$ as in the statement of the theorem, for $t \in (0,b)$ w can write
$$ V(t)=v^{\alpha}(t)J_{\alpha}(t) \tag{10.25}$$
for some piecewise smooth functions $v^{\alpha} : (0,b) \to \mathbb{R}$. ( Here and in the remainder of this proof, the summation convention is in effect, with Greek indices running from $2$ to $n$.)
In fact, each function $v^{\alpha}$ has a piecewise smooth extension to $[0,b]$. To see why, let $(x^{i})$ be the normal coordinates centered at $p$ determined by the basis $(w_i)$. For sufficiently small $t>0$, we can express $J_{\alpha}(t)$ and $V(t)$ in normal corrdinates as
$$ J_{\alpha}(t) = t \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\alpha}}|_{\gamma(t)} , \ \alpha=2,\dots,n \\
    V(t)=v^{\alpha}(t)J_{\alpha}(t)=tv^{\alpha}(t) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\alpha}}|_{\gamma(t)}.$$
( The formula for $J_{\alpha}(t)$ follows from Proposition 10.10. ;

Proposition 10.10. Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian or pseudo-Riemannian $n$-manifold and $p\in M$. Suppose $\gamma :I \to M$ is a geodesic such that $0 \in I$ and $\gamma(0)=p$. For every $w\in T_pM$, the Jacobi field $J$ along $\gamma$ such that $J(0)=0$ and $D_t J(0)=w$ is given by
$$ J(t)=d(\operatorname{exp}_p)_{tv}(tw).$$
where $v=\gamma'(0)$, and we regard $tw$ as an element of $T_{tv}(T_pM)$ by means of the canonical identification $T_{tv}(T_pM) \cong T_pM$. If $(x^i)$ are normal coordinates on a normal neighborhood of $p$ containing the image of $\gamma$, then $J$ is given by the formula
$$ J(t)=tw^{i} \partial_i|_{\gamma(t)}.$$
where $w^i \partial_i|_{p}$ is the coordinate representation of $w$.
C.f. Coordinate representation of basis element of tangent space with respect to a normal coordinate.  )

Because $V$ is smooth on $[0,\delta)$ for some $\delta>0$ and $V(0)=0$, it follows from Taylor's theorem that the components of $V(t)/t$ extend smoothly to $[0, \delta)$, which shows that $v^{\alpha}$ is smooth there. Because $V(b)=0$, it follows similarly that $v^{\alpha}$ extends smoothly to $t=b$ as well. ( If $J_{\alpha}(b)=0$, the argument is same as for $t=0$, while if not, it is even easier.)
( Next proof is omitted. )
I have no idea what the bold statement is saying. How such mechanism works? How can we use the Taylor's theorem? I think this is my first time seeing this kind of pattern. Can anyone explain this argument more in detail?

use the fundamental theorem of calculus to write $V(t) = t\int \dots$.

Uhm.. I don't understand your intention. How can we use the fundamental theorem of calculus to show the smooth extendibility of $V(t)/t$ to $[0, \delta)$ as in the proof? Can you explain more in detail?

$$V(t) = (\int_{0}^{1}V'(st),ds) t,$$ so $$V(t)/t = \int_{0}^{1}V'(st),ds$$

Why $V(t)/t = \int_{0}^{1}V'(st)ds$ is extendible to $[ 0, \delta)$ smoothly? In the proof in question John Lee wrote "it follows from Tyalor's theorem that.." and can we use the Taylor's theorem? How?

$V$ is smooth on $[0, t)$. By differentiating under the integral sign, we see that $f(t) = V(t)/t$ is smooth. Lee says 'Taylor's Theorem' because the Fundamental theorem of calculus is a special case of Taylor's theorem with integral remainder
